# How do I include table headings in Excel data?

Tags: manipulate, export, list-manipulation

I am trying to generate a table with `Manipulate` and export the results into an MS Excel file.

Fortunately, after a lot of troubles, I was able to get the file export right but the headings were not included in the Excel file. I would be quite grateful for you guys to point to me where I am getting it wrong. Please see my code below:

```
Manipulate[
  nino = 
    TableForm[Table[(a*i)^2 - j^3, {i, 5}, {j, 6}], 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {n, n^2, n^3, k, g, t}}], 
  Button["Export", Export["ndata" <> ToString[a] <> ".xls", nino]], 
  {nino, ControlType -> None}, 
  {a, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: `TableForm` is only a display form. Instead of using it just export your list with table headings attached, i.e.: `Export[..., Prepend[Table[(a*i)^2 - j^3, {i, 5}, {j, 6}], {n, n^2, n^3, k, g, t} ]]`. Also what's with the `Manipulate` here? It doesn't seem to do much of anything that couldn't be better done programmatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exporting to Excel means that you will have forego the use of the `TableHeadings` option of `TableForm`. You can do it like this.

```
dir = SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop"}]];

Manipulate[Column[
  {nino =
     Join[{{n, n^2, n^3, k, g, t}}, Table[(a*i)^2 - j^3, {i, 5}, {j, 6}]];
   TableForm[nino],
   Button["Export",
     Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, "ndata" <> ToString[a] <> ".xls"}], nino],
     ImageSize -> Automatic,
     Method -> "Queued"]}],
  {nino, None},
  {a, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

SetDirectory[];
```

[image: demo]

Then clicking on the export button will produce an .xls file that looks like this:

[image: xls]

BTW: Having negative numbers under a column headed $n^2$ is strange

#### Edit

I am going to recant on my assertion that *Exporting to Excel means that you will have forego the use of the `TableHeadings` option of `TableForm`*. It is a little more work to use the option, but it does result in a better looking `Manipulate` output.

```
Manipulate[
  Column[
    {data = Join[{lbls}, Table[(a*i)^2 - j^3, {i, 5}, {j, 6}]];
     TableForm[Rest @ data, TableHeadings -> {None, lbls}], 
     Button["Export", 
       Export[FileNameJoin[{dir, "ndata" <> ToString[a] <> ".xls"}], data], 
       ImageSize -> Automatic,
       Method -> "Queued"]},
    Right,
    Dividers -> {False, 2 -> True}],
  {data, None},
  {{lbls, {n, n^2, n^3, k, g, t}}, None},
  {a, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo2]